# Trying to convert php to python and getting a syntax error

Tags: python, syntax, curl

I'm trying to convert some php code into python and am using curl.  I've gotten most of it to be accepted, but when it gets to the result = pycurl.exec(Moe) it keeps throwing a syntax error.  I guess that I'm not filling out the exec field correctly, but I can't seem to figure out where it is going wrong.

```
from urllib2 import urlopen
from ClientForm import ParseResponse
import cgi, cgitb 
import webbrowser
import curl, pycurl

Moe = pycurl.Curl(wsdl)
Moe.setopt(pycurl.POST, 1)
Moe.setopt(pycurl.HTTPHEADER, ["Content-Type: text/xml"])
Moe.setopt(pycurl.HTTPAUTH, pycurl.BASIC)
Moe.setopt(pycurl.USERPWD, "userid:password")
Moe.setopt(pycurl.POSTFIELDS, Larry)
Moe.setopt(pycurl.SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0)
Moe.setopt(pycurl.SSLCERT, pemlocation)
Moe.setopt(pycurl.SSLKEY, keylocation)
Moe.setopt(pycurl.SSLKEYPASSWD, keypassword)
Moe.setopt(pycurl.RETURNTRANSFER, 1)
result = pycurl.exec(Moe)
pycurl.close(Moe)
```

Comment: Please include the error message you're getting

Comment: Fyi, usually you use `UpperCamelCase` for classes and `lower_underscore` for variables including class instances. So naming your variable `moe` would be better.

Comment: CGI Error
The specified CGI application misbehaved by not returning a complete set of HTTP headers. The headers it did return are:

  File "C:\Inetpub\wwwroot\EVILWEBS\writefile.py", line 63
    result = pycurl.exec(Moe)
                       ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `result = Moe.perform()` to execute your request.

---

PS:

```
Moe.setopt(pycurl.POSTFIELDS, Larry)
```

Is `Larry` actually a variable? If it's a string, quote it.

Comment: Larry is a string variable.  

if I use Moe.perform then I get the following error

CGI Error
The specified CGI application misbehaved by not returning a complete set of HTTP headers. The headers it did return are:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Inetpub\wwwroot\EVILWEBS\writefile.py", line 27, in 
    Moe = pycurl.Curl(wsdl)
TypeError: Curl() takes no arguments (1 given)

Answer (score 1):

`exec` is a reserved word in Python, you cannot have a function of that name. Try reading the pycurl documentation to see what function you should be calling.

I haven't used pycurl myself, but maybe you want to call `Moe.perform()`?